# How to get widget by property value in Gtk+ 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, gtk3

Is it possible to get a widget just by a value of its property? for example I have a Gtk.Box, which changes during program, but all the time all version of this box have position 2 in parent container. And I must send it as a parameter to function.
Certainly, I could make a loop for all elements in container, checking if position ==2 and run function for an item when it is, but I hope there is more elegant way...

Comment: Do you need a GtkTreeview, perhaps?

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I know, GtkTreeview is on higher level and doesn't have access to position of objects in containers. And I must pass object pointing it by its position in container.

Comment: That's exactly what Treeview does. You can update information by cell, row or column. And the user can select/edit whatever information they wish.

Comment: You might want to add what you are doing, because your request seems weird. Maybe there is an altogether different way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I don't want to update information by cell. I have some comboboxes in which I select paremeters for a query in a database (to populate cells). Additionally one of comboboxes is dynamically changed by selected position of others - after that change its a new combobox, not the first one. But when I pass selected parameters for my query in the database a function search for the old one and I get an error - thats why I want to pass parameter from changing combobox pointing it by its position not by name.

Comment: To clear - treeview in my table has 12 columns in n rows and above it there is a header with 5 comboboxes packed by pack_start in Gtk.Box

Comment: How about `box.get_children()[2]` ? Not tested, just something I think should work.

Comment: Why not just store a pointer to that box for later use?

Comment: box.get_children()[2] worked, thank You. And You were right in one more thing - there was a better way to accomplish my goal (Gtk.ListStore.clear(), and then append([something_new]))